# Python sorting multilevel index

Tags: python, indexing

Lets say I have a few multilevel indexes:

```
1 Tokyo square
2 Bethany Church
10 ABC Tower
11 Wise Man
```

using this code I have an error

```
pred=pred.reindex(sorted(pred.columns), axis=1)
   
pred
```

How do I sort index so it will show it in ascending order based on the number 1, 2....? currently my index 10 is before 2?

Thanks

Comment: what is your object? a pandas dataframe? can you provide it as its constructor? flat text is ambiguous to represent multiindexes

Comment: This will be because the numbers are being represented as strings. *"10" < "2" == True* whereas *10 < 2 == False*